# What exactly is Beast?

Tags: x-1999

In the anime series X (*X/1999*) Satsuki Yatōji uses a machine called Beast to aid the Dragons of Earth.

Satsuki Yatōji is shown to have the ability to interact with computers through cables inserted into her skin and to hack into any technological system however she does more than just hack system such as controlling cables remotely when connected to Beast and Beast's cable seem to be able to act on their own.

Also, all the Dragons seem to have some sort of supernatural ability as well. While Satsuki may not possess an ability herself, Beast was provided to her by Kanoe, and Beast itself doesn't look like just a machine.

I am wondering if Beast is something more?